# How do I run fsck manually?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, system-recovery, fsck

My computer was turned off and on again and again directly not the proper way Now its not booting or starting correctly, this also happened before but at that time it did somekinda auto recovery thing but now it requires for run fsck manually 
[image: this is the link of the picture of the screen]

Comment: What error? Please [edit] your question, use proper punctuation (it's hard to make sense of right now), include missing details. Also avoid [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029): ask about the issue that you're facing, not how to apply your idea of a solution.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually

Comment: Also https://askubuntu.com/questions/888835/how-do-i-do-a-manual-fsck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `fsck /dev/sda6` should fix it.

What most likely happened was that your unclean shutdown left the filesystem in a inconsistent state, and to avoid further damaging it, Ubuntu doesn't want to boot until it's fixed.